# Service not working in Kotlin Multiplatform Application

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have Backend service my Application in Android native part. It was working fine but suddenly stoped working. I have tried everything and looked into every piece of code but not found any issue.

I am calling service from Activiy as follows:

```
Intent(this, TestService::class.java).also { intent ->
startService(intent)
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
android:name=".Services.TestService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
</service>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the Problem.
The issue was the Package name should be of only small letters then it can register properly in Manifest.XML.